# use a callback inside a sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, callback

I want to use a callback function for when the sort method has finished sorting the numbers inside the array. I would think that it must look something like this:

```
  totals.sort(function(a, b){b - a; continuation()});
```

Somehow though, my code isn't doing what it is supposed to do. Therefore I am wondering wheter or not it is because of this line of code. In case it is, can anyone please tell me the appropriate way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You don't need to do this, sort is synchronous.

Comment: Also, your sort function needs to return a value.

Comment: oh of course, I feel a little embarrassed for not thinking of that. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: Also, you should return a value in your compare function + this function is called numerous times for sorting purposes. Not once when sorting is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` function doesn't accept an argument that does that, so you can't.

It isn't needed though: `sort` isn't asynchronous in the first place.

Just sort the array, then do whatever else you want to do afterwards.

```
totals.sort(function(a, b){b - a; });
continuation()
```